# Reorganise panel data in Stata

Tags: panel, stata, reshape

I am working on my own data with Stata and I had a problem to restructure my data in a panel format.

More specifically, I have a dataset that have a first column of years, a second column of individuals and the rest of the columns include the variables.

The first lines of the dataset include observations of the first year (y1) for all the individuals of my sample. The following lines include obervations for the second year (y2) for all the individuals of my sample. the following lines include observations for the third year (y3) for all the individuals of my sample.

I want to have a dataset where the first lines will include observations for the first individual of my sample over all years. The following lines will include observations for the second individual over all years. The following lines will include obervations for the third individual over all years. etc.

Here is an example: I need to change the format of this dataset:

```
year  id   var1    var2    var3
y1    1    ..      ..      ..
y1    2    ..      ..      ..
y1    3    ..      ..      ..
y2    1    ..      ..      ..
y2    2    ..      ..      ..
y2    3    ..      ..      ..
y3    1    ..      ..      ..
y3    2    ..      ..      ..
y3    3    ..      ..      ..
```

into this format:

```
year  id   var1    var2    var3
y1    1    ..      ..      ..
y2    1    ..      ..      ..
y3    1    ..      ..      ..
y1    2    ..      ..      ..
y2    2    ..      ..      ..
y3    2    ..      ..      ..
y1    3    ..      ..      ..
y2    3    ..      ..      ..
y3    3    ..      ..      ..
```

Comment: 1. Posting what code you have tried (and a small sample of your data) would likely help you get an answer. 2. I would advise you to consider whether you would be better served by long-form data rather than wide-form data (of either sort). Most analyses in Stata (and I would dare to say panel data analyses in particular) are much easier (understatement) to conduct with long-form data. 3. It looks, from your example, like all you are doing is `sort`ing the data. Note that you haven't changed the structure of the data at all -- just the order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it is just about sorting the data. I tried the command sort id year and it worked.    Many thanks

Comment: PS: I misinterpreted your description of the data (when viewing the unformatted data sample). Your data already are in long form. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

To close this out with an answer: This question seems to be about sorting the data, so

```
sort id year
```

yields the desired result.

You may also want to consult some guides -- e.g., `help gs`.